# Core Data - Order of objects in a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app is a music library app, the user has their songs, and they can create playlists.
I want the order of the songs in the playlist to be in the order that the user adds those songs to that playlist.

My core data objects:

```
Song
=====
name
duration
album

artist (to one relationship)

Playlist
========
title

songs (to many relationship)
```

I have a tableview of playlists, each row in that table shows the title of the playlist and the name of the last song added to that playlist.

**I have two questions:**

1. How can i know what was the last song the user added to the playlist? even more how can I know the order of the songs in a given playlist?
2. How should I fetch that last song name when i'm building the playlists tableview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the relationship type to ordered in the core data editor. This will mean that you now get an `NSOrderedSet` of songs instead of just an `NSSet` of songs

Comment: What about my second question, I know I can than call [self.playlist.songs.allObjects lastObject] but is that the right way to do for each cell? Will it fetch all objects or only the one I need? I'm looking for the most efficient way to get the last song name

Answer (score 5):

You could model the order explicitly by adding a new entity to the data model.

```
PlaylistOrder
=============
index (an integer of some type)
playlist (to one relationship)
song (to one relationship)
```

When you fetch `PlaylistOrder` managed objects, filter by playlist `title`, and sort by `index`.

Why not just add the `index` attribute to the `Song` entity? Presumably, a single song could belong to multiple playlists.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered relationships are expensive.  Expensive enough that they should be avoided unless there is simply no other way to sort the data.  In your case, there is another way to sort the data.

If you add a `insertedAt` or `createdAt` property to your `Song` entity you now have something you can sort off of and get the order of the songs.  That will be faster and perform better than using an ordered relationship.  This becomes more apparent as you collect more data.

From there you can sort the `Song` entities on that new property and even build a convenience method in `Playlist` entity to determine what the last `Song` was (sort by date property, grab the last object).

### Update 1

Since a song can be in multiple playlists then you could create a meta object between playlist and song.  Effectively a join table with data in it:

```
Playlist <<--> SongMeta <-->> Song
```

The `SongMeta` entity would have `createdAt` as a property and then it gives you a place to add additional information about the song in that playlist.  I have seen this design in music applications in the past.

However, if you foresee a user's ability to arbitrarily re-arrange the playlist then that definitely does fall within the ordered relationship's narrow useful scope.  Just be mindful of the performance cost associated with it.

Comment: but a song can be in many playlists so one property wont help me here

Comment: I would think those to-many arrows would be flipped? Wouldn't each Song have many SongMeta's - the order that song takes in various playlists. And each Playlist would have  many songMetas - One for each song in the playlist.

Comment: Honestly @BigBoy1337, I don't remember at this point. This post was from over six years ago.